# Protractor won't start in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, protractor

Today I had a problem with starting protractor. Chrome started up, but it stayed blank.

Nothing happened, but command prompt showed up with title "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

I suppose it's because new version of Chrome (46.0), but I'm not sure. This is my config file:

```
exports.config = {
specs: ['Client/e2e/Automated.js'],
baseUrl: 'http://google.com/', 
framework: 'jasmine2',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    print: function() {},
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 1660000
},

 multiCapabilities: [{
'browserName':'chrome'}...
```

I started in Firefox also and it worked.

Should I change something in my config file or what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happened? Can you post the console logs of selenium webdriver if at all it is showing any error? Thanks

Comment: FYI, I just updated chrome to latest 46, and selenium+protractor are working fine.

Comment: This is shown to console log:      "Running "protractor:args" (protractor) task
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://10.80.1.163:58176/wd/hub"  This is the first time I had problem like this one and also command promt with chrome.exe is showing today. @Girish Sortur

Comment: After 10min, this showed up:    C:\Users\stefan\Work\branches\develop\UserSite\CBPm\CBPm\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\err
or.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stackt
race informa

Comment: You are using quite outdated version of chromedriver, try updating https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads.

Comment: I had the same issue today. So I uninstalled protractor and then installed again (the last version). It solved my problem.